# Find the two least common positive values that divides both 40131 and 41405

Tags: functions

I'm completely new to mathematica, and got stuck on a question. If I needed to find the least 2 common dividers for 40131 and 41405, how would I code it?

What i want is: 
Prime Factorization of 40131 is:
3 x 3 x 7 x 7 x 7 x 13  =>  32 x 73 x 131

Prime Factorization of 41405 is:
5 x 7 x 7 x 13 x 13  =>  51 x 72 x 132

And the least common 2 factors are 7 and 13. But how do I manage to code that I get 7 and 13 in the program? Ty for all help!

Comment: What have you done to solve this homework?

Comment: Use `Divisors[GCD[40131, 41405]]` to find all common divisors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you need the prime common factors: in such a case, see codes below.

```
Intersection[FactorInteger[40131][[;; , 1]], 
 FactorInteger[41405][[;; , 1]]]
```

or

```
Select[Divisors[GCD[40131, 41405]], PrimeQ]
```